# No image in Clipboard after PrintScreen. How to wait while it will available?

Tags: wpf, image, screenshot, clipboard

I created a global keyboard hook. It works correctly, PreentScreen press is caught. But after pressing need wait for some time until the image on the clipboard will appear. If at once try to get a picture - there will be null. How is it better to implement?
My code:

```
...
if (e.KeyPressed == Key.PrintScreen)
{
    // There need to wait before get a picture
    if (!Clipboard.ContainsImage()) return;
    var screenshot = Clipboard.GetImage();
    ...
}
```

PS: "Thread.Sleep(... ms)" not work. Probably because it is happening in the main thread.

Comment: have you tried doing this using the intended API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649033(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution. Maybe bad, but it works.

```
if (e.KeyPressed == Key.PrintScreen)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (!Clipboard.ContainsImage());// There need to wait before get a picture
            var screenshot = Clipboard.GetImage();
            ...
        }
        catch { }
        finally { Clipboard.Clear(); }
    });
    th.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}
```

PS: I also added a check time of the cycle, so it does not run forever. I did not show it in the code not to complicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but what if u removed the if statement... like try something like this...

```
if (e.KeyPressed == Key.PrintScreen)
{
    BitmapSource screenshot = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetImage();
}
```

Comment: It is nothing on will affect. As I pointed out in comments - during checkout there will be null.
I need wait for the image to the clipboard will be available, but I do not know how to do it correctly.

Comment: oh wait I see what ur doing wrong lol sorry.... screenshot should not be a var object I've updated my answer sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would set a timer to call me back in 250ms, and let the KeyPressed event continue.  Use a try/except/sleep wrapper around the clipboard call in case it fails. You'll be butting heads with apps that are monitoring the clipboard legitimately (through the clipboard notification API), so you should expect (and handle) failures due to someone else having the clipboard open.